# Don't know how to make a Dynamic jQuery CHART(flot : sin-cos)

Tags: javascript, dynamic, charts, playframework, flot

So I am a junior and I am trying to understand how things work here.
I am using `jquery.flot.js` to make an `interacting` chart.

What I am trying to do?
I want to take this values (the values from the table) and make a chart:

```
@for((c,w)<- map){

    <tr>
        <td class="val">@c</td> 

        <td class="time">@w</td>
        <br>
    </tr>
}
```

> I am using play framework and I get those values from my server through a `map`...

In `@c` I will get values that represents the humidity from an environment;
 
*and* 
In `@w` I will get the timestamp from each value.

And this is the script for the chart :

```
 $(function() {

        var sin = [],
            cos = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
            sin.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
            cos.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
        }

        var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [
            { data: sin, label: "sin(x)"},
            { data: cos, label: "cos(x)"}
        ], {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: -20,
                max: 90
            }
        });

        $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
            position: "absolute",
            display: "none",
            border: "1px solid #991F7A",
            padding: "2px",
            "background-color": "#E68AB8",
            color : "#000",
            opacity: 0.70
        }).appendTo("body");

        $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

            if ($("#enablePosition:checked").length > 0) {
                var str = "(" + pos.x.toFixed(2) + ", " + pos.y.toFixed(2) + ")";
                $("#hoverdata").text(str);
            }

            if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length > 0) {
                if (item) {
                    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                    $("#tooltip").html(item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y)
                        .css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5})
                        .fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                    $("#tooltip").hide();
                }
            }
        });

        $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
            if (item) {
                $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
                plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
            }
        });

        // Add the Flot version string to the footer

        $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
    });
```

Maybe some of you played with this plug in, this is how things look :

[image]

I want to take the values from the time (`@w`) and put them on the axe : x , and the humidity (`@c`) on y ...
Can somebody help me please .... !?
Thank you.

Comment: You can write a javascript data array on the page or use something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991519/flot-chart-from-data-table/29942441#29942441) to convert the values from the table to an data array.